# Possible to remove route from React-Router's HashRouter history?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We're using `HashRouter` and would like to remove routes from history if the user makes them invalid (by deleting the underlying data for that link.)

Ideally we'd like to remove an entry from the `history` stack so that we can simply using `goBack()` and `goForward()` without having to get complicated. Otherwise we need to do a lot more convoluted stuff to correct for if a user goes back to a route that doesn't exist.

Comment: Your user is able to type such url that gets invalid directly to the address bar, so you probably need to handle it anyway. In most cases, such handling is just a `history.goBack()` call.

Comment: @Shlang the user cannot manually modify the route in our environment.

Comment: @Silbox then you may use BrowserRouter with custom `history` object or use MemoryRouter in order to have full access to the `history` object. HashRouter seems the worst option for your case.

Comment: @Shlang can you point me to documentation on how one can do that with `MemoryRouter`? I did see that it has a couple additional options, but I didn't see anyway to achieve removing an entry from `history`. BrowserRouter isn't a possibility in our environment, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Silbox, sorry I was wrong regarding BrowserHistory and MemoryRouter. You may pass history object to [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object) and you may write your own implementation of `history` that would allow doing whatever you want

Comment: @Shlang when you say "your own implementation" what would that look like? We're already using `createHashHistory()` to provide `history` to the HashRouter. Is what you're describing something more/different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210465/discussion-between-shlang-and-slbox).